# Using AWS cognito from plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

Hoping someone can shed some light on using Cognito with plain JavaScript.  No npm, no webpack, just plain JavaScript.  I found a post that had a great example including the required AWS JavaScript libraries.  I worked from this example until I ran into the problem of sign out not working.  I thought perhaps the libraries in the example were out of date so I went looking for the latest.  This is where things got confusing.  In the example I had the following JavaScript libraries - amazon-cognito-identity.min.js, aws-cognito-sdk.min.js, and aws-sdk.min.js.  I assume that aws-cognito-sdk must no longer exist?  I updated the other two and see that there is an amazon-cognito-auth library.  Do I need that?  Anyhow with those three libraries the existing code no longer functions.  I end up with errors like "AWSCognito is undefined" etc.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction and show me where the downloads, documentation, etc for using Cognito in plain JavaScript are

Comment: What do you mean by plain JavaScript? Can you link the tutorial that you had followed?

Comment: Plain JavaScript is probably the wrong way to say this.   I am building a chrome extension that requires sign in and sign out functions. In the extention, JavaScript is included in script tags in html or through references in the extension's manifest.  I'm not using NPM, I can't use "require", etc.

Comment: https://medium.com/@gmonne/custom-authentication-using-aws-cognito-e0b489badc3f

Comment: The tutorial is using the Identity JS SDK. You could refer to the [source code](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js) while designing your authentication engine.

Comment: You can use webpack to expose a library by attaching it to the window object. Then you could play around with it in regular JS by using the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Find hereunder a template I created for myself to work from. It is in "plain javascript" and in an angularjs app.

My template: https://github.com/PouncingPoodle/aws-cognito-angularjs/tree/master
based on: https://github.com/takanorig/aws-cognito-angularjs

**Always make sure that you use the correct versions of scripts and the correlating apiVersion when you call a Lambda function for example**

There might be bad practice involved but as far as I could research it should be all fine.